# merge sort algorithm loop for copying elements in sub arrays

Tags: algorithm

[image: merge algo pic from clrs]

can somebody tell me in line no 5 and 7 of the algo why its not written as 
l[i]=A[i]
and r[i]=A[i]
in the loops

Comment: image attached from book clrs

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure if I'm correct, because I can't see the rest of the algorithm, but it seems like you have already sorted A[p,...,q] and A[q+1,...,r] and you want to merge them so the whole A[p,...,r] become sorted. You copy elements from A[p,...,q] to L array and elements from A[q+1,...,r] to R array.

For some reason, instead of making loops from p to q and from q+1 to r, the author decided to calculate n1, amount of elements in A[p,...,q] and make a loop from 1 to n1 which gives exactly the same effect (I guess knowing the length n1 shortens the code later). Since i-th element is equal p + i - 1 you have to write L[i] = A[p + i - 1]. Same thing with n2.

You could write L[i] = A[i] if you decide to make a for loop from p to q (I mean FOR i = p to q in line 4). Same goes for R[i] = A[i] with loop from q+1 to r.

Comment: if use this loop R[i] = A[i] with loop from q+1 to r , let q=4, then loop will go from 5 to r. But the book author is starting the R' s loop from 1 , i think he is considering another list rather than a global array